# Laravel - How to access database which is connected via PhpStorm tools

Tags: database, laravel, phpstorm

I connected to my database in PhpStorm (in Data Source and Drivers using General and SSH/SSL tabs) but I don't know how to access it in Laravel.

```
DB::connection('dev_admin@127.0.0.1')->select("SELECT * FROM oc_order")->get();
```

this command doesn't work, it says Database `[dev_admin@127.0.0.1]` not configured.

`dev_admin@127.0.01` is the name of the database in PhpStorm. Please help. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#configuration

Comment: In general it is more common to have a local db for local development. Then having your database and nginx that is gonna be production, staging or test environment on the same server. Connecting to your production database or external can make critical errors happen, downing db's etc.